# HOW TO:: Notify user IIS application pool recycle or IIS reset?

Tags: iis

Is there any way through code to notify users about IIS application recycle or IIS reset?

better if I could check using APIs so that i can dispatch the message to central server which could sent out email or send instant messages?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One of the easiest, I have realized is to use powershell. You could use something like:

> Get-EventLog -log system -Source IISCTLS,WAS,W3SVC | Format-Table
>   Source,Message -Wrap -auto | Out-File some1.txt

to get a good txt file containing all the app pools restarts and IIS restarts.

If you would like to do it through IIS API then check http://www.muqeetkhan.com/how-to-use-microsoft-web-administration-from-powershell

You could easily translate that powershell script to a C# program as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may use windows scheduled tasks with event trigger for this purpose. They are relatively simple to implement: find some recycle event in eventvwr (in System logs locate an event with ID 5074), right click on it, choose "Attach a Task to this event". Then choose "Start a program" and specify your batch/powershell script or an exe, etc. You can pass any data from the event as an argument. You can also define multiple events as triggers for this task.